# Replacing None with incremental values is replacing appended sublist as well

Tags: python

I have one list of sublists from which I am deriving another list of sublist by appending repeated sublist. Now when I am trying to replace `None` with incremental value, I notice that appended sublist is also changing. Can someone help me understand what am I doing wrong here?

```
b = [[1,None,3],[4,5,1],[7,None,2]]
a = [] 
for i in b:
    for rp in range(i[2]):
        a.append(i) 
print(b)
print(a)
c = 0
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i][1]==None:
        a[i][1] = c
        c = c + 1       
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[[1, None, 3], [4, 5, 1], [7, None, 2]]
[[1, None, 3], [1, None, 3], [1, None, 3], [4, 5, 1], [7, None, 2], [7, None, 2]]
[[1, 0, 3], [1, 0, 3], [1, 0, 3], [4, 5, 1], [7, 1, 2], [7, 1, 2]]
```

Expected output:

```
[[1, 0, 3], [1, 1, 3], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 1], [7, 3, 2], [7, 4, 2]]
```

Comment: `a.append(i.copy())`. Right now you are appending a reference to the same list multiple times

Comment: You are appending references to the inner lists in `b` when you use `a.append(i)`, so when you change one of them, it changes all of them

Comment: @MarkTolonen can you close?